# Debugger throws "Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp" error

Tags: java, debugging, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

I've run into a problem while trying to get the Java Debugger extension in VS Code to work. When I run it, an error is thrown that says:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:   -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=gasp
```

From what I can see this error causes the debugger to stop before execution of the program. I unset  `_JAVA_OPTIONS` in `.bashrc` but that did not fix it.

Any ideas as to what the problem is and possible resolutions to it?

EDIT: I changed development platforms before seeing ZhangTe's answer, but since it solved the problem for another user I'm marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the following to /etc/profile

```
unset _JAVA_OPTIONS
```

Then, reboot your computer or reload the profile file.